# RData File written in R, cannot be read in Python

Tags: python, r, rpy2, rdata

I encounter a 'bad restore file magic number' when I try to read a .RData file.

I use R version 3.4.3 and Rstudio Version 1.2.5033. I have written the Data file in R with:

```
save(object1, object2, object3, file = 'CV_folds.RData')
```

From R I can read that file without problems. When I try to read that same file from Python (Version 3.8) using Pycharm (version 2020.1) with the rpy2 package with:

```
robjects.r['load']('CV_folds.RData')
```

I get an error as follows:

```
R[write to console]: Error in load(name, envir = .GlobalEnv) : 
  bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
Calls: sys.load.image -> load
```

Anybody an idea what is going wrong?

Comment: What happens if you use the latest version of R, release 3.6.3?

Comment: Hi, Len, I tried that and now wrote the RData file with R version 3.6.3. I still does not work.The format of the error message changed, but that is all.....

Comment: In rpy2, try pointing to full, absolute path as error indicates *no data loaded*.

Comment: Have you tried write the file in another format, such as `write.csv()` or `saveRDS()` on an object by object basis, and read that into Python? Also, what happens if you write only one object with `save()` and try to read it into Python.